# Opening a ng-bootstrap modal content from a home component of an app module. (Angular2 newbie)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have been trying to implement ng-bootstrap modal over bootstrap4 beta but can't seem to understand from other examples where actually it is injected and if I need to inject content and component all the way from app module.  I have put a plunker example
http://plnkr.co/edit/koPxsafjmUIhpXKY6rFC

I want to open a modal window from a link in navigation which is a home component in app module And the modal is separate component where the content is either embedded in component or loaded as template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <base href="." />
    <title>ng-bootstrap demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@^2.4.1/client/shim.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.10/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.10/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@^0.1.8/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@^0.19.40/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app').catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the app module

```html
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HomeComponent} from 'src/home.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent } from './modal-component';



@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, JsonpModule, NgbModule.forRoot()], 
  declarations: [HomeComponent, NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent],
  entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
}) 



export class AppModule { }
```

And this is the home component

```html
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {ModalComponent} from '@src/modal-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/home.content.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private modal: NgbdModal) {}
  
  openAbout() {
    const modalRef = this.open(ModalComponent);
 
  }
  
}
```

And here is the modal component

```html
import {Component, Input onInit} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbdModalContent, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div #content class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal ) {}
}
```

the call on the home.content.html is

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_self" (click)="openAbout(content);" title="About Estate Management"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-ark-info-circle"></span><span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">About</span></a>
```

Can someone help me through this?

Comment: Sorry in advance since the code I pasted here is a bit different to plunker as I updated a bit on plunker while trying in the meantime. But the issue is still the same as not knwowing.

Comment: Ok there was quite a number of mistakes which I copied from template then changing without properly referencing.  And I had to create EntryComponent property in appmodule for ModalComponent. 

Also relative paths to html files using moduleID:module.id is giving errors for no reason I understand other than Angular version may be,  so using absolute paths helped.

Plunker did not save the work properly either I will paste a working example here.

Comment: I have made several changes and I made it work. Here is a working code https://plnkr.co/edit/ZcD8NnHe0RqlwTDOA5Pz?p=info